# Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Forbidden

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am new to SOAP API and WSDL. I had this project to use the SOAP API and I used this code from one of the stackoverflow answers. But when I am running this, I am getting this error.

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Forbidden in 'directory' Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__doRequest('...') #1 directory): SoapClient->__call('method', Array) #2

Here is my code:

```
<?php

try{
$wsdl_url = 'API';
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl_url);
} catch (SoapFault  $e) {
 echo 'Error in Soap Connection : '.$e->getMessage();
}

$params = array(
'LBID' => '1',
'YearID' => '23',
'SectorId' => '3',
'Password' => 'password'
);

$result= $client->getProjectDetails($params);
print_r($result);
?>
```

I am able to access the api by directly putting it on address bar. The soap connection is established, no errors there. But this error is showing on the method calling line, `$result= $client->getProjectDetails($params);`

I don't know what this error is, I tried searching the forums but couldn't get any idea about this. Can anyone help?

Comment: Your target soap server has an authentication/authorization layer of some kind and you didn't pass correct credentials/token in your input data, perhaps some kind of headers, that's why you get the Http Forbidden status.

Do you have a documentation for you soap server API?

Comment: @SergioRinaudo But I am able to access the api directly. The API team is saying that it is some error in my code. I am not able to find what it is. I have tried every forum, every stackoverflow solutions.

Comment: When you say that you are able to access the API directly, do you mean that you see the WSDL from the browser?

May I ask you the WSDL endpoint?

Comment: Yes I can see the method name and all. See here : https://snipboard.io/9seS0y.jpg

Comment: Ok, but this is not related with the problem, you can access the wsdl but subsequently get a 401.
The main reason is that this service has an authentication/authorization layer as previous said.
Not having  the capability to test it I would recommend to ask your service supplier for examples, I advice to use SoapUI

Comment: I tested with SoapUI, and I got the response correctly.

Comment: So there is a problem when create the XML payload by SOAPClient, to debug this you could create a custom soap client class that extends SoapClient and override __doRequest, then dump the raw request created.

Comment: Can you show me a sample???

Comment: @SergioRinaudo I tried using NuSoap Library, what I am getting is this https://snipboard.io/0kbjXB.jpg  with error `2019-11-14 07:32:43.193084 nusoap_client: Error: HTTP Error: Unsupported HTTP response status 403 Forbidden (soapclient->response has contents of the response)`

Comment: If you take the XML request from nuSoap and run it with SoapUI, do you get a correct response?

Comment: I have send the details to you.

Comment: I sent you an answer, this service need some kind of authentication. The problem is not php or SoapClient